# Update a table in SQL server (without output from select)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table (tran) with the following values:

```
Set  Type  Acc         Type        Tran               Value
---- ----- ----------  ---------- ------------------- -----------
1    BS    87411       CCHQ       Other Transactions  -200
1    BS    87411       RECPT      Other Transactions  200
1    BS    87411       CCHQ       Other Transactions  -200
1    BS    87411       RECPT      Other Transactions  200
```

How do I update this table to order the items by Type. I should mention this code is part of an SP and I cannot use select since I don't want output by updating the table.

I tried something like:

```
update a
set Value = sum(Value)
from tran a
group by TranType
```

but this doesn't work, shows an error "incorrect syntax near group"

Comment: You have 2 cols as TYPE. which 1 you want to order and plz also include the Desired O/P.

Comment: Unrelated but: shouldn't `group by TranType` be `group by Tran, Type`?

Comment: Yes sorry I meant group by Type

Comment: Desired output would be:
`1    BS    87411       CCHQ       Other Transactions  -400`
`1    BS    87411       RECPT      Other Transactions  400`

Comment: What you are struggling with is why it is generally recommended not to store calculated values in an OLTP. It seems strange to me to change the value of your transactions to an aggregate value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the things you can do, I'm afraid there's no getting away from a DELETE statement.. as you won't be able to overwrite your existing data by having a unique row with a summed up value without deleting it.

```
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Type2) AS UniqueID, *    --- Create Unique ID if you don't already have one.
            INTO #tmpTransactionTypes
            FROM dbo.TransactionTypes_Test;

            UPDATE A
            SET A.Value = B.Total
            FROM #tmpTransactionTypes AS A
             INNER JOIN (
                  SELECT  Type2, SUM(Value)  AS Total
                  FROM    #tmpTransactionTypes
                  GROUP BY Type2) AS B  ON A.Type2 = B.Type2;


            DECLARE @FirstValue INT = 1
            DECLARE @LastValue INT = (SELECT MAX(UniqueID) FROM #tmpTransactionTypes)

            WHILE @FirstValue <= @LastValue

            BEGIN

                DELETE
                FROM #tmpTransactionTypes
                WHERE UniqueId = @FirstValue;

             SET @FirstValue = @FirstValue +2

            END


            SELECT  *
            FROM    #tmpTransactionTypes;

        -- COMMIT TRANSACTION
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Result:

```
       UniqueID  Set    Type1   Acc     Type2      Tran              Value
         2        1       BS   87411    CCHQ    Other Transactions  -400.00
         4        1       BS   87411    RECPT   Other Transactions   400.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way. Try this instead:

```
update a
set a.Value = t.Total
from tran a
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT TranType, SUM(Value) Total
   FROM tran
   GROUP BY TranType
) AS t ON a.TranType = t.TranType
```

Comment: I tested this, this only doubles the original values. All four lines are still there but now they're each 400 (or -400)

Comment: @Setzor - This is exactly the same query you wrote, may be you need a different query. Please edit your question and explain what are you lookin for

Answer (score 0):

update a
set Value = sum(Value)
from tran a
group by Tran, [whitespace char is missing] Type

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, a nice way to do this is using an updatable CTE and window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, sum(value) over (partition by trantype) as newvalue
      from tran
     )
update toupdate
    set vaule = newvalue;
```

That said, it seems strange to overwrite the original data with the summation.  Shouldn't you put it in another column or another table?

Answer (score 0):

The 'order' of a table in SQL is by definition not in the storage.

If there is no 'order by' clause in the requesting SQL statement the order of the results may be random (or given by the database preferred fetching routines).

If there is an 'order by' clause the result will be sorted by that clause anyway.